# ReactJS - Add slug to url (dynamic slug in frontend)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web

I'm trying to create something like here on stackoverflow:

When I enter this URL:

```yaml
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70615440
```

it will update the url to:

```yaml
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70615440/refactor-switch-statement-to-reduce-code-complexity
```

The url is possible to visit by id. It will add / update the slug to the url. I can also use the a random slug `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70615440/xxx` and it will update it to the correct one :`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70615440/refactor-switch-statement-to-reduce-code-complexity`

xenForo does something similar:

```yaml
https://xenforo.com/community/threads/200874/
```

```yaml
https://xenforo.com/community/threads/xenforo-2-2-8-patch-1-and-add-on-updates-released.200874/
```

How can I achieve something like this in a React app? How is that behavior called?

Answer (score 2):

Here is working example I have created with useEffect only. You can refer this [Click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-darkness-cy91rz?file=/src/ProductPageWrapper.js)
It will work for both http://example.com/product/:id as well as http://example.com/product/:id/:slug

**BrowserRouter Section from App.js**

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route exact={true} path="/products/:id" element={<ProductPage />} />
        <Route
            exact={true}
            path="/products/:id/:slug"
            element={<ProductPage />}
        />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**ProductPage.js**

```
import { useNavigate, Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

const ProductPage = (props) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { id, slug } = useParams();

    const handleRedirection = useCallback(() => {
        // Get id and slug from asynchronous calls
        // Assuming below object returned from API
        
        const response = { id: 1, slug: "slug1" };

        if (id === response .id && slug === response .slug) {
          // Don't do anything as the user is on right page
        } else if (id === response .id && slug !== response .slug) {
            navigate("/products/" + response .id + "/" + response .slug);
        } else {
            console.log("ID doesn't exist on server");
        }
    }, [id, slug, navigate]);

    useEffect(() => {
        handleRedirection();
    }, [handleRedirection]);

    return <Link to="/">Go to Home</Link>;
};

export default ProductPage;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this overshadow subpaths such as `/products/create`?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this kind of routing, I have implemented two routes with react-router-dom. So in App.js:

```js
<Route
  exact={true}
  path="/products/:id/:slug"
  component={ProductPage}
/>
<Route
  exact={true}
  path="/products/:id"
  component={ProductPageWrapper}
/>
```

In this case, if the slug was present, it would go directly to ProductPage, but if it was not present, it would fall into the the ProdutctPageWrapper which is a redirect to ProductPage. So in ProductPageWrapper.js

```
import slugify from 'slugify';
import { Redirect, useParams, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { fetchItem } from 'utils/Fetchers';

function ProductPageWrapper({ children, ...rest }) {
  const [productSlug, setProductSlug] = useState('');
  const params = useParams();
  const history = useHistory();
  useEffect(() => {
    // Get the slug from where you stored it or set it so you can use it in the 
    // Redirect. I use slugify to create slug, but you can do it however you prefer
    fetchItem('/api/products/' + params.id, function (err, product) {
      if (err) {
        history.push('/error-page');
      } else {
        setProductSlug(
          slugify(product.title, {
            lower: true,
            strict: true,
            locale: 'en';,
          }),
        );
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Redirect
      to={{
        pathname: `/products/${params.id}/${productSlug}`,
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

In the ProductPage.js I also check if the slug is correct, if not I use history.replace:

```
import { useHistory, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function ProductPage (props) {
  const { slug, id } = useParams();
  const history = useHistory();
    useEffect(() => {
    // Get the product info and check if the slug is correct
    fetchItem('/api/products/' + params.id, function (err, product) {
      if (err) {
        history.push('/error-page');
      } else {
        if (slug !== product.slug) history.replace(product.slug);
        // do what you need with the data
      }
    });
  }, []);
  // ... rest of the component
}
```

Comment: That's a quite interesting idea! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's called *routing*. You can install [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) and use **useHistory** and **useLocation** hooks. The usage is very simple.
From documentation about **useLocation**:

> The useLocation hook returns the location object that represents the current URL.

You can save the current URL in *pathname* and compare it with the id,
if they match, you can use **useHistory** for navigation.

[Read more](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)

Example code:

```
const { pathname } = useLocation();
const history = useHistory();
const handleChange = () => history.push("/questions/70615440/refactor-switch-statement-to-reduce-code-complexity");

useEffect(() => {
    if(pathname === "/questions/70615440"){handleChange()}
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This idea does not work with `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70615440/xxx`. It should support also the url with the slug (for SEO)

Comment: In that case, you can just check if your pathname includes that specific id, and if it does, then redirect.

In useEffect:
if(pathname.includes("questions/70615440")) {handleChange()}